# Problems On Rolled Roofing Section Of New Roof?

Tags: roof, roofing

We just had a new roof put on our house a week ago.  The front of the house is all architectural asphalt shingles, and the rear addition is rolled roofing.

The house withstood the first rain just fine w/ the new roof.  Im still paranoid that something was done improperly and might cause problems down the line - probably PTSD from an awful contractor we hired last year.

Im pretty ignorant when it comes to roofing - but I took a few photos of stuff near the rolled roofing section that caught my eye.

Mostly stuff around pipes and vents.  Want to make sure those were done properly - as I know those can be the weak spots on a roof.  Also curious why, on the rolled section - there’s a spot where there are a couple of random seams near the skylight, the rest of the rolled panels seem to be contiguous.   Maybe they started to run out of material and had to cobble things together?  Also this weird little “tab” looking thing on one corner of our skylight.

Don’t really care if everything is done aesthetic perfect, as long as it functions as it should.  Anything jumping out to u guys?  Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]